# Replace JNDI lookup with mock object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, jndi

I'm using jndi to perform a database lookup :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mydb"
        resource-ref="true" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

In a spring context file I invoke the constructor using :

```
<bean id="myController " class="com.MyController">
<constructor-arg index="0" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

I no longer want to expose "myDataSource" via a jndi lookup, so a I create a mock object which is of same type as "javax.sql.DataSource" and use it instead as a constructor parameter :

```
<bean id="myMockDataSource" class="com.mock.MyMockDataSourceConnection">
</bean>

<bean id="myController" class="com.MyController">
<constructor-arg index="0" ref="myMockDataSource" />
</bean>
```

The mock object just returns a dummy connection.

Is this the correct way so as to longer use jndi lookup when want to use a mock object instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Spring's `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` class, which is useful for building JNDI tree without needing a Java EE container.

```
class JndiMock
{
    public void init()
    {
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
        builder.bind( "jdbc/mydb" , new YourDummyConnectionClass() );
        builder.activate();
    }
...
}
```

(This is from memory, but should give you the idea). You can instantiate it as a singleton right in your application context XML descriptor using the `init-method` attribute:

```
<bean id="jndimock" class="your.package.JndiMock" init-method="init" />
```

and make it is created before the `jee:jndi-lookup`.

Cheers,